# How to programtically know the price of a cryptocoin in a specifi exchange?

Tags: exchange-server, swap, price

I want to learn the way to programatically (API, WS...) query the price of a cryptocoin in a particular exchange vs a pair.

For example know the price of MATIC vs USDT in quickswap exchange: https://quickswap.exchange/#/swap

I was inspecting the querys (F12>Network>Fetch/XHR); but I do not get any clue to do that.

I am not looking for the code, just the way to do that.